# How to keep redis database pod running in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

I created a pod which serve redis database and i want to leave it running when complete. Containers are meant to run to completion. Do i need to create and infinity loop which never ends ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: lfccncf/redis:latest
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the container has a process which keeps running then you don't need to use infinite loop. In this case the container will run the `redis` process.The `dockerfile` will have the `RUN` command to execute the process.

Also I suggest you use a standard redis image or a [helm chart](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/redis) to deploy redis.

Here is [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/guestbook/) on running PHP guestbook app with redis

Answer (score 1):

it is no need

```
command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]enter code here
```

delete it